# is there any way to solve error message in login page overlap with the textfield

Tags: flutter

```
          Container(
                // Text Field for password
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                width: 320,
                height: 60,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffffffff),
                ),
                child: TextFormField(
                  maxLines: 1,
                  // use to hide password
                  obscureText: _obscureText,

                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                    hintText: 'Password',
                   //    errorStyle:     const TextStyle(height: 0),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                          _obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
                      onPressed: _toggle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  //  Password validation , show an error message when enter wrong values
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter a password.';
                    } else if (value.length < 6) {
                      return 'The password must be at least 6 characters long.';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              //Error message design
              if (_passwordError.isNotEmpty)
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0.0,
                  left: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Container(

                      margin:const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                            child: RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                               text: _passwordError,
                                   style: const TextStyle(
                                     height: 0,
                                       color: Colors.red,
                                         fontSize: 12,
                         ),
                      ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

I am unable to style error message properly , could anyone help me

i try to style error message but it overlap with the textfield

Comment: The mistake has been solve, I have removed the box decoration and it has corrected the every thing